# Conditional cell fill

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements

Hi I am trying to build a long term Excel sheet for my church scheduling. I want to be able to format a cell fill if that cell has contents. eg. I want it to go green if I have entered the name of the preacher for a particular day. Alternatively colour red if there is no entry. It doesn't have to be both, one or the other would be OK. Excel seems to be happy for me to format a cell contents but not the fill.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Go to 'Conditional Formatting'
- 'Highlight Cell Rules'
- 'Text that contains'
- Enter preacher name
- Choose fill settings from dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to highlight any cell that is empty, right? not based on the name of the preacher?

1. mark the area you want to have the rule apllied on
2. Go to "Conditional Formatting"
3. "New rule"
4. Select the last option in the list, it should be something like "formatting rule based on this formula" (I dont know the exact term because my Excel is not in English)
5. enter this rule: =ISBLANK(A1:A6) -> A1:A6 is the area you selected in first step
6. set the formatting on any color you like and hit OK

more here: [Link](https://exceljet.net/formula/highlight-blank-cells)